# Mysql subquery limit or use multiple queries

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select just 2 questions per status. I know mysql doesn't support limits for subqueries but I've seen workarounds which I can't figure out how to use for this query. Is this a one query problem or do I have to use extra queries? I'm trying to select 2 rows for each status.

Without `LIMIT 2` the following query will work, but it has too many results hence the need to limit it.

```
SELECT id FROM questions WHERE status_id = c.status_id LIMIT 2
```

Query:

```
  ...
    FROM questions q, users u, users lu, tags t, question_tags tt, connection c
   WHERE q.user_id = u.id
     AND tt.tag_id = t.id
     AND tt.question_id = q.id
     AND c.user_id = 100
     AND q.last_user = lu.id
     AND q.id IN (SELECT id FROM questions WHERE status_id = c.status_id LIMIT 2)
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY q.date DESC
```

Comment: You will get 1 as a resultset

Comment: I know, my select is irrelevant for the question

Comment: Are you gettig your expected result?

Comment: If your `select` (code) is irrelevant why is it posted here?  What are you trying to do? What is "2 questions per status"?

Comment: BTW: do you realise that you **don't need** the subquery at all? You can do the same with extra where clause

Comment: @GermannArlington You mean 'AND q.status_id = c.status_id' ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant

Comment: @MoyedAnsari The join already exists, so just and extra where clause is needed

Comment: @MoyedAnsari Can you tell me how it can be done with a join please :)

Comment: @amiawizard I mean join is there you just need to add where clause and having which will gives you results having 2 questions like  ....AND q.status_id = c.status_id 
GROUP BY q.id
Having count(q.id) = 2
ORDER BY q.date DESC

Comment: I don't want a condition for status with 2 questions, I'm trying to limit the amount of questions in the result set to 2 per status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
    FROM questions q, users u, users lu, tags t, question_tags tt, connection c
   WHERE q.user_id = u.id
     AND tt.tag_id = t.id
     AND tt.question_id = q.id
     AND c.user_id = 100
     AND q.last_user = lu.id
     AND q.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM questions WHERE status_id = c.status_id, 
                  SELECT MAX(id) FROM questions WHERE status_id = c.status_id AND id < 
                        (SELECT MAX(id) FROM questions WHERE status_id = c.status_id))
GROUP BY q.id
ORDER BY q.date DESC
```

Ugly, I know, but it should work.